# TypeError: start() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self' ao tentar usar o módulo chronometer

Tags: python, python-3.x

Instalei o módulo chronometer 1.0 para o python 3.4: [chronometer module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/chronometer/)

Tentei usar o atributo start() do método Chronometer, mas dá um erro: requer um argumento 'self'

```
>>>from chronometer import Chronometer as crmt
>>>crmt.start()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    crmt.start()
TypeError: start() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
>>>crmt.start(self)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    crmt.start(self)
NameError: name 'self' is not defined
```

Alguém me pode explicar como resolver este problema e por o cronómetro a funcionar corretamente, e qual é o código para escrever um cronómetro funcional?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quando você faz...

```
from chronometer import Chronometer as crmt
```

...você está importando a classe `Chronometer` do módulo `chronometer` para o espaço de nomes atual e a apelidando de `crmt`.

Note que `chronometer.Chronometer` é uma classe (ou seja, uma definição) e não um objeto. Quando você faz `crmt.start()`, o interpretador do Python vai procurar o método `.start()` no que ele acha que é um objeto do tipo `Chronometer`, **vai encontrar**, já que `start()`, de fato, está definido dentro de `Chronometer`, vai tentar executar, mas não vai conseguir porque o parâmetro `self` não foi passado.

`self` é um parâmetro que recebe o próprio objeto, que é passado automaticamente quando você faz algo assim: `objeto.metodo()`. É similar ao `this` do C++ e do Java, mas Python optou por tornar o `self` um parâmetro explícito.

O que fazer, então? O que você provavelmente quer é o seguinte:

```
from chronometer import Chronometer
crmt = Chronometer()
crmt.start()
```

A segunda linha cria um exemplar de `Chronometer`, o que fará a terceira linha rodar sem problemas.

Comment: obrigada, resultou na perfeição